# Using HIghcharts on Codeigniter to get data name and total

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, highcharts

i just stuck on my code, and i can't continue my program, can someone help me please to break my wall and i can continue my code. 
i use highcharts on codeigniter and this is my code :

Controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $chart=$this->Model_mou->get_data();
    $this->load->view('mou', $chart);
}
```

Model :

```
function get_data() 
{ 
  $this->db->select('dn_ln as name, count(dn_ln) as total');
  $this->db->from('mou');
  $this->db->group_by('dn_ln');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}
```

View :

```
series: [{
      name: 'Precentage',
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [
      <?php
         foreach ($chart as $x) {
         echo "['" .$x->name . "'," . $x->total ."],\n";
         }
      ?>

       ]
  }]
```

this is my error :
[error message code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjsjt.png)

so i want to show name and total on my pie chart.
i hope someone out there can help me to check my code and fix it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Codeigniter, the view expects to get data from the controller as an array. Within the view, you access directly the array element, not the array itself.

So if you're passing `$chart` into the view and `$chart` contains `$name` and `$total` you call those.

You could "hack" the behaviour in the controller a little bit (so you can still use `$chart` in the view) by placing `$chart` inside an array which is then passed into the view. Try this:

```
public function index()
{
    $chart=$this->Model_mou->get_data();
    $viewdata = array(
        'chart' => $chart,
    );

    $this->load->view('mou', $viewdata);
}
```

By making this small change in your controller, your view will start working as you expect (as it'll take the `$chart` element -which is an array itself- from the `$viewdata` array that was passed from the controller)